# Annotations complement javadoc tags

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

Why is it said that Annotations complement javadoc tags?

Comment: "it is said": by whom? where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible reason is that the use of annotations can overlap with that of Javadoc tags.

The best example of course is the `@deprecated` Javadoc tag and the `@Deprecated` annotation, which both indicate the same thing.

Both annotations and Javadoc tags provide metadata about code elements.

Answer (score 5):

Annotations are code and will be represented at the byte code level.  Javadoc tags are  documentation level artifacts and are meta-data for the javadoc processor.

If retention level of the annotation class is runtime, you can reflect over the class and access the annotation; no such possibility exists for the javadoc tag (unless you have access to source files and are parsing them).

So, in a very narrow sense (e.g. a javadoc processor that does bytecode processing, such as generating code) the tags can be considered "complementary" [sic] to annotations, but that's about it.

Overall, its a bad meme to carry around in your head as it really doesn't inform the true distinction between these two entirely different constructs.